# Export 3D text for threeJS

Tags: export, three.js

Blender v2.82: I have three models, all 3D text converted to mesh with colours and material added.  I want to export these 3 models for use in a reactJS application using threeJS.

I am not sure of the process here.  Do I have to unwrap the UV before exporting?

I reference the model in the code here:
const { nodes } = useLoader(GLTFLoader, "models/1_BigW5-Wmesh.glb");

The files are exported as .glb - will they still work with the threeJS renderer?

There are many demos of this but all seem to use cubes and spheres, not an imported model...

Comment: Select the text open search menu (Space, F3, depending on your settings) type in convert, choose Convert to -> to mesh. You won't be able to change the text in Three, for that you'd be much better off creating the text in Three.js.

Comment: You can test the GLB models in a viewer like https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ — if they work there, they e exported correctly and should work in threejs. You only need UV unwrapping if the models have textures.